# JavaScript : Why do i have to click twice in the table to execute the colorActiveLine function?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a function to change the background color of the clicked line in my HTML table but when I load the page I have to click twice in a line to change her color.

When I have already change the background color of a line, it is ok. I can click only once to change the color.
The problem is only when I have just loaded the page.

Here an example of my problem :

**HTML**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
        <style media="screen" type="text/css">
        table {border-collapse: collapse;} tr {border: 1px solid;} td {border: 1px solid;}
        </style>
    </head>

    <body onload="populateTable()">
        <table>
            <tbody id="fruitTable">
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript**

```
// POPULATE THE TABLE ON LOAD WITH SOME DATA
function populateTable () {
    var tableRef = document.getElementById('fruitTable');

    var newRow;
    var newCell1;
    var newCell2;

    // ADD LINE 1
    newRow = tableRef.insertRow(-1);
    newRow.style.background = '#98A2DD';
    newRow.onclick = colorActiveLine;
    newCell1  = newRow.insertCell(0);
    newCell2  = newRow.insertCell(1);
    newCell1.innerHTML = "apple";
    newCell2.innerHTML = "green";

    // ADD LINE 2
    newRow   = tableRef.insertRow(-1);
    newRow.style.background = '#98A2DD';
    newRow.onclick = colorActiveLine;
    newCell1  = newRow.insertCell(0);
    newCell2  = newRow.insertCell(1);
    newCell1.innerHTML = "banana";
    newCell2.innerHTML = "yellow";

    // ADD LINE 3
    newRow   = tableRef.insertRow(-1);
    newRow.style.background = '#98A2DD';
    newRow.onclick = colorActiveLine;
    newCell1  = newRow.insertCell(0);
    newCell2  = newRow.insertCell(1);
    newCell1.innerHTML = "coconut";
    newCell2.innerHTML = "white";
}

// CHANGE BACKGROUND COLOR ON CLICK
function colorActiveLine() {
    var lines = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');

    for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; ++i) {
        lines[i].onclick = function() {
            // SET ALL BACKGROUND COLOR TO BLUE
            for (var j = 0; j < lines.length; ++j) {
                lines[j].style.background = '#98A2DD';
            };
            // SET ALL BACKGROUND COLOR TO ORANGE
            this.style.background = '#DDC498';
        };
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because your event handler function `colorActiveLine` attaches its own anonymous event handler to each `<tr>` element in the document, here:

```
lines[i].onclick = function() {
```

The contents of this function are not executed until you re-click the element.

[Here is a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q6Lxnor4/) which demonstrates that if you remove the attachment of a new event handler within `colorActiveLine`, the row is coloured correctly when clicked for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you've nested the onclick events in your rows.

When the row is created, you assign `colorActiveLine` to the onclick event. In the `colorActiveLine` function, you then create another anonymous function and assign it to the onclick, and it's this function that actually changes the colour which is why you have to click twice.

Your colorActiveLine function just needs to be this:

```
// CHANGE BACKGROUND COLOR ON CLICK
function colorActiveLine() {

var lines = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');

    for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; ++i) {
        lines[i].style.background = '#98A2DD';
    }
    // SET ALL BACKGROUND COLOR TO ORANGE
    this.style.background = '#DDC498';

}
```

JS Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/1xh5kk3p/